# How do I prove that there is a complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analytic-functions

I have the following problem:

> Prove that there exists an analytic function $$f:\{z\in \Bbb{C}:|z-1|<1\}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$ when $|z-1|<1$.

We have just shown this fact for the $l$-th root but somehow I did not see it now where to start. I know the analytic function which describes $e^z$ maybe this helps?

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should look at any construction online, eg with an integral

Comment: So but do I really need to construct it?

Comment: Because we haven't seen the notion of a complex integral

Comment: Seems the easiest way. $$f:z\mapsto\int_L\frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{\zeta}$$When $L$ is the straight line segment from $1\to z$ - as your region excludes $0$ - is one way to do it. You need to only prove now that it satisfies the functional equation - Hint: consider the power series of $\exp(f(z))$ about $z=1$

Comment: @FShrike but I don't think that I can do this since we haven't seen a complex integral yet, even though it is maybe really easy

Comment: @OliverDiaz sorry but what is a branch logarighm? so I mean when we constructed the root we used the taylor expansion $(1+x)^{1/l}=...$

Comment: Well if you can show that/know that every complex $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is expressible as $re^{it}$, by asserting that $-\pi\lt t\le\pi$ you can assert injectivity, thus bijectivity - and you’ll get your inverse. A different choice of $-\pi,\pi$ will yield a different branch. This is the meaning of branched logarithm as far as I know

Comment: Use the expressions $h(z)=\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{(1-z)^k}{k}$ which is clearly absolutely convergent for $|z-1|<1$ hence uniformly convergent on $|z-1| \le r<1$ so giving an analytic function and show that it works so $e^{h(z)}=z$ (for example show that $h'=1/z, z \ne 1$ etc)

Comment: **I said “consider the power series of $\exp(f(z))$ about $1$ but it is much easier to instead consider the power series of $f(\exp(z))$ - once you’ve shown differentiability of course

Comment: @Conrad oh nice but could you maybe explain how one get to this formula so I mean what is the inuition behind $h(z)$?

Comment: The taylor series of the logarithm is $\log (1-x)=-\sum x^k/k, |x|<1$ so you substitute $x \to 1-z$ here; the original one is obtained by integrating the geometric series since the derivative of the logarithm is $-1/(1-x)=-\sum x^k$ and taking care of the constant etc -

Comment: aha so you "cheated" a bit using that you know the taylor series for the logarithm and then show that it works for our case?

Comment: of course but that is basic real analysis 101 stuff one is supposed to know when studying complex analysis

Comment: ah sure okey so I will try it.

Comment: @Conrad sorry if I disturb again but can I derive the equation $e^{h(z)}=z$ on both sides to say that it holds because then I think I would get $\frac{1}{z}e^{h(z)}=1$ which gives me the same equation when I multiply by $z$?

Comment: yes sure - make sure you get the right equation as there may be a minus in front there

Comment: sorry where do you mean a minus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rather pedestrian way to do this is by constructing directly a sort of logarithm function. Here is one approach.

Given a real number $\theta_0$ and using polar coordinates,  every $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $$z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$$
where $r=|z|$ and $\theta\in[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$.

- The *angle* $\theta$  is called **argument** of $z$, which we denote  by $\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z)$. Let $\ell_{\theta_0}=\{rx^{i\theta_0}:r\geq0\}$,  $\Omega_{\theta_0}=\mathbb{C}\setminus\ell_{\theta_0}$. Define a function $L_{\theta_0}:\Omega_{\theta_0}\rightarrow\big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\big)\times(\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$ by
  \begin{align}
    z\mapsto \log(|z|) +i\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z),
  \end{align}
  where $\log$ is the usual logarithm function on the real line.
- $L_{\theta_0}$ is bijective function whose inverse is the exponential function restricted to $\big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\big)\times(\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$.
- Since $\exp\in H(\mathbb{C})$ and  $\exp'=\exp\neq0$, $L_{\theta_0}\in H(\Omega_{\theta_0})$ by the inverse function theorem for holomorphic functions, and $L'_{\theta_0}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ for $z\in\Omega_{\theta_0}$ (see remark below).
- The function $L_{\theta_0}$ is called the **$\theta_0$--branch of logarithm**.  The branch $L_{-\pi}$ is called the **principal branch of logarithm**. When the branch of logarithm is clear from the context, we use $\log$ to denote the function $L_{\theta_0}$.

Notice that the ball $B(1;1)=\{z:|z-1|<1\}\subset \Omega_{-\pi}$ and so, $e^{L_{-\pi}(z)} = z$ for all $z\in B(1;1)$.

---

Remark: The complex inverse function states that if $f:D\rightarrow U$, $D,U$ regions in $\mathbb{C}$, is analytic and bijective, and $f'\neq0$  on $D$, then $f^{-1}:U\rightarrow D$ is also analytic and $(f^{-1})'(w)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(w))}$. This can be proved by using methods of Calculus on the plane plus checking that the Cachy-Riemann equations are satisfied by $f^{-1}$.

--